# Keep consecutive number in list if the difference greater than a certain value

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I would like to keep consecutive values in a list with difference >= than X
Let's say I have this list:

```
list = [1, 50, 70, 75, 100, 110]
```

and I would like to keep consecutive number numbers whose difference is >= 20:

```
A = [1, 50, 70, 100]
```

To do this I'm using now this code:

```
distance = 20
A = []
for i in (list):
    if not A or (i - A[-1]) >= distance:
        A.append(i)
```

There is any other way to do this with itertools or more-itertools?
Thank you!

Comment: If the list were an array, you could calculate differences with `arr[1:]-arr[:-1]`, and test that with a `diff>=20`.  Then use that to select elements to keep.  Is that enough to get you started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 50, 70, 75, 100, 110])
>>> mask = np.diff(arr) >= 20
>>> mask = np.insert(mask, 0, True)
>>> arr[mask]
array([  1,  50,  70, 100])
```

Answer (score 2):

For list `l`, we could do -

```
[l[0]]+[l[i] for i in range(1,len(l)) if l[i]-l[i-1]>=20]
```

For array `a`, it would be -

```
a[np.r_[True,np.diff(a)>=20]]
```

If you want to consider differences as absolute ones -

```
a[np.r_[True,np.abs(np.diff(a))>=20]
```

Comment: Almost, `[l[0]]` should only be added if l[1] - l[0] >= 20, so a conditional is needed.

Comment: @cs95 Think `[l[0]]` would always be added being the first element.

Comment: Hmm, so for `[1, 2, 3]` should the result be `[]` or `[1]`?

Comment: @cs95 Think it would be [1].

Comment: That intuitively doesn't make sense but I suppose OP is fine with it :-)

Comment: @cs95 Think if you run OP's loopy code, might make sense as it gives us [1] for that one. Intuitively, since there's nothing before the first element, you would have to take it irrespective of anything.

Comment: Oh yes, I noticed that. Definitely not throwing shade on your answer, it's perfectly fine (as always!). I just feel the premise is flawed/not as clear as it could be. But OK to leave as is. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

With simple *generator* function:

```
def filter_diff(lst):
    v = lst[0]
    yield v
    for n in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[n] - v >= 20:
            v = lst[n]
            yield v

lst = [1, 50, 70, 75, 100, 110]
print(list(filter_diff(lst)))   # [1, 50, 70, 100]
```